# Socket connection issue with A server (ExpressJS + Nodejs + Nginx + SSL)

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, nginx

I have a fully working production server with the following setup:
NodeJS configured with Nginx and SSL on port 3000. ExpressJS as front.

Now i am trying to add some socket work inside.
I have created a new file called server.js with the following code:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;

net.createServer(function(sock) {

// We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

// Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
sock.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
    // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
    sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');

});

// Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
sock.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
});

sock.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

I have added this line in my main app.js file:

```
require('./app/server');
```

Now when I start the server it prints as expected the line:
"Socket Server listening on 127.0.0.1:6969"
and
"NodeJS Production server listening on port 3000"

Now when I try to reach the socket server with:

```
netcat [destination] 6969
```

It doesn't work.
But when I tried it on my localhost development server which has no SSL and Nginx it did work.

Probably I have to add some Nginx configuration or a secure connection to see the socket but I couldn't find any clues online.

Please any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Plain TCP sockets don't actually need Nginx to operate. They're also not encrypted and therefore don't make use of SSL. The most probable reason why your code doesn't work in production but works locally is that you listen to a loopback interface `127.0.0.1`. This interface is by no means connected to an external network and you can't reach it from outside.

You should listen to whether an IP, assigned to a particular interface on the server, or to `0.0.0.0` which essentially means "listen to all interfaces of the machine".